# Need to not increment a loop when a condition is met

Tags: bash

I have a shell script that seismogram files in a folder and plots them to a pdf. When the pdf is exited, the user is prompted to see if the plot is of good quality or not. If the user types one of four specified prompts, I use a case statement so that the file is copied into a corresponding directory. If the user types a response that is not in the specified list, I want the code to replot the pdf until the user gives a correct response. How could I go about doing that?

I've read online that I need to be using a while loop instead of a for loop, but I don't know how to loop through files in the folder while also allowing the code to stop on a certain file until a correct input is given.

```
for sac in $event/*R.sac; do
    ***preprocess the data***

    read -p "Is this a good SKS event? Type 'q1' for a really good event, 'q2' for an okay event, 'ns' for a null split, or 'be' for a bad event:   " -n 2  answer
    echo
    case "$answer" in
        q1 )
            echo -e "\nVery good event chosen\n"
            if [[ ! -e $q1/$goodstat && ! -e $q2/$goodstat ]]; then
                mkdir -p $q1/$goodstat
                mkdir -p $q2/$goodstat
                echo "$goodstat created in $q1 and $q2"
            else
                echo "$goodstat exists in $q1 and $q2"
            fi
            cp -a $event/*$sacname*[R,T].sac $q1/$goodstat
            cp -a $event/*$sacname*[R,T].sac $q2/$goodstat

            ;;
        q2 )
            if [[ ! -e $q2/$goodstat ]]; then
                mkdir -p $q2/$goodstat
                echo "$goodstat created in $q2"
            else
                echo "$goodstat exists in $q2"
            fi
            cp -a $event/*$sacname*[R,T].sac $q2/$goodstat

            ;;
        ns )
            echo -e "\nNull Split chosen\n"
            if [[ ! -e $null/$goodstat ]]; then
                mkdir -p $null/$goodstat
                echo "$goodstat created in $null"
            else
                echo "$goodstat exists in $null"
            fi
            cp -a $event/*$sacname*[R,T].sac $null/$goodstat

            ;;
        be )
            echo -e "\nBad event chosen\n"
            conditional=true
            ;;
        * )
            echo -e "\nWrong input\n"
            ;;          
        esac
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just wrap your `read` and `case` block inside a while loop that doesn't end until a valid answer is given:

```
for sac in $event/*R.sac; do
    ***preprocess the data***

    while true; do
        read -p "Is this a good SKS event? Type 'q1' for a really good event, 'q2' for an okay event, 'ns' for a null split, or 'be' for a bad event:   " -n 2  answer
        echo

        # Start by assuming answer is good
        answer_ok=1

        case "$answer" in
            # (cases for valid answers omitted for clarity)

            * )
               echo -e "\nWrong input\nTry again\n"

               # Flag answer as bad
               answer_ok=0
               ;;          
        esac

        # If user gave a good answer, break out of the while loop
        if (( answer_ok )); then
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

An alternative and perhaps cleaner method of terminating the `while` loop (depending on how many cases you have) would be to just add a `break` in each valid case, just before the `;;`. This would break out of the `while` loop. But the `*)` case wouldn't have a `break`, so if it hits that case it will just loop back around again.

For example:

```
while true; do
   read -p "Is this a good SKS event? Type 'q1' for a really good event, 'q2' for an okay event, 'ns' for a null split, or 'be' for a bad event:   " -n 2  answer
   echo

   case "$answer" in
      q1) # do stuff
          break
          ;;
      q2) # do stuff
          break
          ;;
      ns) # do stuff
          break
          ;;
      be) # do stuff
          break
          ;;
      * )
          echo -e "\nWrong input\nTry again\n"
          # No break - loop back around again
          ;;          
   esac
done
```

Yet another method would be to re-check the answer after the `case` block, just before the end of the `while` loop:

```
while true; do
   read -p "Is this a good SKS event? Type 'q1' for a really good event, 'q2' for an okay event, 'ns' for a null split, or 'be' for a bad event:   " -n 2  answer
   echo

   case "$answer" in
      q1) # do stuff
          ;;
      q2) # do stuff
          ;;
      ns) # do stuff
          ;;
      be) # do stuff
          ;;
      * )
          echo -e "\nWrong input\nTry again\n"
          ;;          
   esac

   # If "$answer" is valid, break out of the loop.
   if [[ "$answer" =~ ^(q1|q2|ns|be)$ ]]; then
      break
   fi
done
```

The `=~` is a bash-specific operator that performs a regular expression match.

Continuing with this approach, you could use the negated regular expression test as the conditional of the `while` loop (after first initializing `answer` to an invalid answer, so that the conditional will fail the very first time).

```
answer=foo
while [[ ! "$answer" =~ ^(q1|q2|ns|be)$ ]]; do
   read -p "Is this a good SKS event? Type 'q1' for a really good event, 'q2' for an okay event, 'ns' for a null split, or 'be' for a bad event:   " -n 2  answer
   echo

   case "$answer" in
      q1) # do stuff
          ;;
      q2) # do stuff
          ;;
      ns) # do stuff
          ;;
      be) # do stuff
          ;;
      * )
          echo -e "\nWrong input\nTry again\n"
          ;;          
   esac
done
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!!! Thanks so much!